# EFS Restore backup access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

When trying to restore File system from AWS Backup I'm getting the following error:

```
Access Denied
Insufficient privileges to perform this action. Please consult with the account administrator for necessary permissions.
```

[image]

This is weird since I have `AdministratorAccess` under my AWS user:

[image]

The file system created by running the CLI command:

```sh
aws efs create-file-system
```

In addition, I followed [EKSWorkshop](https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/190_efs/launching-efs/) to create the EFS.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you change the policy on the backup vault screen you can start the restore.

It's deny by default.

For example, it works:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "backup:DeleteBackupVault",
                "backup:DeleteBackupVaultAccessPolicy",
                "backup:DeleteRecoveryPoint",
                "backup:StartCopyJob",
                "backup:StartRestoreJob",
                "backup:UpdateRecoveryPointLifecycle"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that simply changing the effect to `Allow` will allow any AWS principal to start a restore of any of the recovery points in the vault. Or worse yet, to delete recovery points. This could have serious data protection, GDPR or even regulatory implications.